# how can you translate virtual address to physical address?

Tags: operating-system

if I have a base of 0x00000432 and some bounds, say 500, how can I translate various virtual addresses to physical addresses?

VA 0x0000043 --> ?
VA 0x0000054c --> ?

Comment: The operating system sets up these mappings, so it can inspect its own data structures. The process generally can not afaik (without help from the OS).

Comment: You would need to (from the kernel) do a page table walk to find the physical address.